# ï»¿ characters in html code uploaded on database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with "ï»¿" characters. I read on the internet that it may be the BOM and/or the charset that isn't set to "UTF-8".
But even with these settings it doesn't work.

Let's get to the point:

I'm making a php page that uploads an HTML file on a Database Table with Dreamweaver.
Then I store the HTML code into a variable with this code:

```
$fileText= file_get_contents($target_file);
```

*where `$target_file` is the uploaded file, something like

```
<html>< head>< /head>< body>hello< /body>< /html>
```

to make it simple (without the spaces in the tags)

Then I store the `$fileText` inside the database using:

```
$sql="INSERT into TABLE (HTMLfile) VALUES ('$fileText');
```

Then when I look at the record in the database, it shows:

ï»¿ `< html>< head>< /head>< body>hello< /body>< /html>`

I have the charset=UTF-8 in both the php page where is the upload and insert codes, and in the html uploaded page. 
Then I did the following thing in Dreamweaver: Edit > Preferences > New Document. Deselect Include Unicode Signature (BOM).

I even tried the various php decode functions, but I don't want to read "&lt html &gt" and such. I want to read "`<html>`" in the database.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem here seems not your PHP file, but rather the uploaded file itself, which is encoded as UTF-8 **with** BOM, and it is up to you to strip it.

Comment: How can I check if BOM is encoded in a HTML file?

I mean, when I open the HTML File (before uploading), it doesn't have ï»¿ characters before < DOCTYPE> etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell PHP to detect and remove the Byte-Order Mark from the beginning of the read file.

```
function strip_bom($string)
{
    if (substr($string, 0, 3) === "\xEF\xBB\xBF") {
        $string = substr($string, 3);
    }
    return $string;
}

$fileText = file_get_contents($target_file);
$fileText = strip_bom($fileText);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!

What is "\xEF\xBB\xBF"? Are they the special characters I see as ï»¿?

Thanks again!

Comment: "\xEF\xBB\xBF" is the escaped representation of the ASCII characters that are the BOM: "EF" is hexadecimal and means 239, BB means 187, and BF is for 191. If you peek into an ASCII table, you'll find that these are the character codes for the three signs ï»¿.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set charset utf8 in mysql.

You have to call mysql function

`$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
  mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);`

thanks

Comment: Is there a way to do this manually? I mean, logging in the database through phpmyadmin, and then change the charset?

I did like this, and the Table already has utf8-general-ci charset.
Or am I looking at the wrong panel?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi you have to set utf8_unicode_ci for table and there fields from phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ok thanks, I did a little research and I found it! Thanks again to everyone! :)